# LINQ query with Inner Join not working when multiple records are added to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a function that requires to return all users except for the ones that have been eliminated, i have written the following query

```
var userLists = await _repositoryContext.User
             Join(_repositoryContext.Eliminations,
             u => currentUser.userID,
             m => m.userOneId,
             (u, m) => new { Eliminations = m, Users = u })
            .Where(u_m => u_m.Users.userID != currentUser.userId && u_m.Eliminations.userTwoId != u_m.Users.userID).Select(u_m => u_m.Users).ToListAsync();
```

This is how the user table would look like

```
 userID: cf321a6a-70de-45c9-997d-de7d2be99a36
 name: test1
 email: test1@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
 userID: b1b2f69a-2100-499b-a0e6-42bbf87290ee
 name: test2
 email: test2@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
 userID: b2be45d2-f065-4321-842d-cc35d29c374f
 name: test3
 email: test3@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

This query works fine when the Eliminations table look like this

```
 userMatchID: 7b2bc383-a818-4662-8f62-4f407650da9e
 userOneWin: 1
 userTwoWin: 0
 userOneId: cf321a6a-70de-45c9-997d-de7d2be99a36
 userTwoId: b2be45d2-f065-4321-842d-cc35d29c374f
```

When `test3 user` is in the eliminations table the query works fine and returns the `test2 user`

```
 userID: b1b2f69a-2100-499b-a0e6-42bbf87290ee
 name: test2
 email: test2@gmail.com
```

But when `test2 user` is added to the eliminations table as well like below

```
 userMatchID: 7b2bc383-a818-4662-8f62-4f407650da9e
 userOneWin: 1
 userTwoWin: 0
 userOneId: cf321a6a-70de-45c9-997d-de7d2be99a36
 userTwoId: b2be45d2-f065-4321-842d-cc35d29c374f
--------------------------------------------------------------
 userMatchID: b9be0fd3-7e4f-4311-901e-c28715ee13d1
 userOneWin: 1
 userTwoWin: 0
 userOneId: cf321a6a-70de-45c9-997d-de7d2be99a36
 userTwoId: b1b2f69a-2100-499b-a0e6-42bbf87290ee
```

the query fails and sends both the currently available users instead of sending an empty list.Which looks like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 userID: b1b2f69a-2100-499b-a0e6-42bbf87290ee
 name: test2
 email: test2@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
 userID: b2be45d2-f065-4321-842d-cc35d29c374f
 name: test3
 email: test3@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

But the result I want is an empty list with no records, the `test1 user` is anyways omitted in the Linq query. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are returning and what you are expecting. From what I read of how you have structured the query with a Join, it looks like you would return back two references to User ID: cf321a6a-70de-45c9-997d-de7d2be99a36 which is probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: @StevePy I have updated the question with the results at each stage and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will work, because it's not how you would do it in straight database. If you had two lists of users, you can't answer "which of these users are not in that list" with solely an inner join - joining them all together and asking for `this.userid != that.userid` wil work when there is only one user in "that" list but as soon as you add two then you'll get all users from "this" list because every one of them is not equal to at least one of the users from that list

```
This
A
B

That
A
```

Only B is returned because B != A, (and A == A)

```
This
A
B
C

That
A
B
```

A is returned because A != B, B is returned because B != A, C is returned twice, because C != A and C != B

In short, don't use inner join for this. Look at a pattern more like

```
var elim1 = DbContext.Eliminations.Where(e => !e.UserOneWin).Select(e => e.UserOneId);
var elim2 = DbContext.Eliminations.Where(e => !e.UserTwoWin).Select(e => e.UserTwoId);
DbContext.Users.Where(u => !elim1.Any(e => e.UserOneId == u.UserId) && !elim2.Any(e => e.UserTwoId == u.UserId))
```

This should map to an sql more like

```
Users u
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM eliminations WHERE u.UserId = userOneId) AND 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM eliminations WHERE u.UserId = userTwoId)
```

The EXISTS is better positioned to answer this than an inner join. You could alternatively inner join the users to the distinct winners rather than the losers. To be honest I don't think your table design is doing you any favours here. I'd have eliminations map a winninguserid and a losinguserid, rather than a user one and a user two and another column to say if the user won and yet another column to say if the user lost. At the moment any time you want the "list of winners" or "list of losers" you have to hit your eliminations table twice, effectively unioning all the userOne where winner1 is true, into userTwo where winner2 is true, which is way more awkward than just having a winner ID and a loser ID column

Comment: I realised it may be a hard thing to do when records keep piling, so for the moment I decided to add a function within the codebase to compare and remove users from the list